# Send Email to Multiple Recepients in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to send Email to Student and Guardian. I have 3 tables Student,Guardian and Users. The Student and Guardian are also in User table. But when i send an email its taking the email address of the First User instead of the Guardian.
This is my Code:

student.rb

```
def student_email(subject, recipient, message)
    user = User.discover(id, recipient)
    UserMailer.student_email(user, subject, message).deliver
end
```

student_controller.rb

```
def send_email
    subject = params[:subject]
    recipient = params[:email][:recipient]
    message = params[:message]
    if subject.empty? || recipient.empty? || message.empty?
        flash[:alert] = t('email_invalid')
        @student = Student.shod(params[:student_id])
        redirect_to email_students_path(@student)
    else
        @student = Student.shod(params[:student_id])
        @student.student_email(subject, recipient, message)
        flash[:notice] = t('sent_email')
        redirect_to email_students_path(@student)
    end
end
```

user_mailer.rb

```
def student_email(user, subject, message)
    @user = user
    user = "#{@user.email}"
    @message = message
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "#{subject}")
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.current
    Thread.current[:user]
  end
 # setter for current user
  def self.current=(user)
    Thread.current[:user] = user
  end
 # Method for find student role and return
 def student
   return unless role == 'Student'
   Student.shod(student_id)
   ArchivedStudent.where(student_id: student_id).take
 end
 def parent
   return unless role == 'Parent'
   Student.shod(student_id)
   Gaurdian.where(student_id: student_id).take
 end
 # method return if role is employeee
 def employee
   return unless role == 'Employee'
   Employee.shod(employee_id)
 end
# create users employee
 def create_user_employee(employee_number, email)
   employee_number.each do |emp_no|
   UserEmployees.create(email: email, employee_number: emp_no)
end
end
   def create_user_student(admission_no, email,phone1)
    admission_no.each do |admission_no|
      UserStudent.create(email: email, admission_no: admission_no,phone1: phone1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you share user.rb file

Comment: @Sajin  
I've shared my user.rb file please check it.